# Customised Scroller Disappearing With Tabs

Tags: php, javascript, css, tabs

I would like some help with this problem please.

I am trying to create a php website with tabs and to keep the same customised scroller in every tab. These scroller codes I found works fine but the customised scroll bar stops showing in tab 2. I notice that this happens when I start using the functions for the tabs (CSS & Javascript).

The **Sample** website can be found here --> http://www.swan10.nl/stuff/scroll/Scroller.php

Tab Functions and Scroll Functions have been marked accordingly in Scroller.php.

The codes for the tabs were also found and modified, perhaps one of them is cancelling the other? If yes, will there be a way to fix this?

This problem has been frustrating me for hours now...Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it is because you are reusing the same id in your html. You have two divs that both use `id="mycustomscroll"`. ID's must be unique to each element on the page. Your flexcrollstyles.css files targets an element with that id to style the scrollbar.

```
#mycustomscroll {
 /* Typical fixed height and fixed width example */
 width: 490px;
 height: 520px;
 overflow: auto;
 /* IE overflow fix, position must be relative or absolute*/
 position: relative;
 padding: 5px;
 background: none;
}
```

If you want to resuse css styles across elements then you should look into using classes first. Until you can produce clean code it is difficult for people here to diagnose what is wrong. But fix that to start.

Comment: I know that you can only use "id tags" once. However I used it twice WITHOUT the tab functions and it works fine. Also I tried to change everything into a class because I know that's the right way to do it but it doesn't want to work as a "class"...so I am forced to "break the law"... Feel free to try it. If you are able to change it to a "class" and make it work, please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: People aren't going to take the time to try and figure it out if the code framework is bad. Things may work in your browser, but maybe they don't work in safari or chrome or ieX or firefox. Start with the right way and ask why it does not work. There is also a lot of css and code jumbled around. Give people a chance by telling them what ids/classes are tied to what css and what they do.